# Displaying Sub Folder Name From A folder using php

Tags: php, subdirectory

I want to display the subfolder names in a folder contained .

How can i do this using php code?
This is the code:

```
function read_folder_directory($dir)
    {
        $listDir = array();
        if($handler = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) {
                if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db" && $sub != "Thumbs.db") {
                    if(is_file($dir."/".$sub)) {
                        $listDir[] = $sub;
                    }elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$sub)){
                        $listDir[$sub] = $this->read_folder_directory($dir."/".$sub);
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($handler);
        }
        return $listDir;
    }
```

When iam using this i get all file names also.I need only folder names.

Comment: please point out why did none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=list+folders+php solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **is_file** part

```
function read_folder_directory($dir)
    {
        $listDir = array();
        if($handler = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE) {
                if ($sub != "." && $sub != ".." && $sub != "Thumb.db" && $sub != "Thumbs.db") {
                    if(is_dir($dir."/".$sub)){
                        $listDir[$sub] = $this->read_folder_directory($dir."/".$sub);
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($handler);
        }
        return $listDir;
    }
```